# how to change Z Elevation of circle in canvas after drawing?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas

I have a circle i'm drawing in my canvas 
then i draw another shape on top of it, 
The end result should be that the new shape i'm drawing needs to be
Below the first circle i'm drawing

Is there a way to change the elevation of the old circle to be on top again ?

i don't want to draw another circle on top of everything because i want to call this function 3, 4 times a second

here is my Class:

```
Paint ciclePaint = new Paint();
        ciclePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cicleShapeOutline));
        ciclePaint.setStrokeWidth(40f);
        ciclePaint.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Paint innerCiclePaint = new Paint();
        innerCiclePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cicleShapeOutline));
        innerCiclePaint.setStrokeWidth(3f);
        innerCiclePaint.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2f, getHeight()/2f, (600f), ciclePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2f, getHeight()/2f, (450f), innerCiclePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2f, getHeight()/2f, (300f), innerCiclePaint);

        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2f, getHeight()/2f, (150f), innerCiclePaint);



        //THIS NEEDS TO SHOW BEFORE THE THREE CIRCLES

        Paint canvasFillForTestings = new Paint();
        canvasFillForTestings.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        canvas.drawPath( pathsArray.get(7), canvasFillForTestings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw that new shape before the circles to appear below. The z-order depends on the drawing order.

Comment: the thing is i will always draw the new shape after, because it comes as an input later on. i could draw a new shape after, but it will be really heavy on the app